# Отсортировать файлы по возрастанию даты в имени

Tags: python, файлы, сортировка

Имеется список файлов, в названии которых присутствует дата

```
a = ['03.04.2023.XML',
 '17.04.2023.XML',
 '27.03.2023.XML',
 '10.04.2023.XML',
 '18.04.2023.XML',
 '21.04.2023.XML',
 '14.04.2023.XML',
 '25.04.2023.XML',
 '13.04.2023.XML',
 '29.03.2023.XML',
 '28.03.2023.XML',
 '07.04.2023.xml',
 '19.04.2023.XML',
 '30.03.2023.XML',
 '05.04.2023.XML',
 '26.04.2023.XML',
 '06.04.2023.XML',
 '30.03.2023.XML',
 '07.04.2023.XML',
 '27.03.2023.XML',
 '28.03.2023.XML',
 '10.04.2023.XML',
 '29.03.2023.XML',
 '14.04.2023.XML',
 '24.04.2023.XML',
 '13.04.2023.XML',
 '11.04.2023.xml',
 '17.04.2023.XML',
 '19.04.2023.XML',
 '12.04.2023.XML',
 '20.04.2023.XML']
```

Как отсортировать их в правильном порядке, чтобы мартовские файлы были первые, а потом шли уже апрельские. Нужно универсальное решение, те хардкодинг именно под апрель и март не подойдет

Обычной сортировкой не удается получить нужный результат

```
d = sorted(a)
>>>
['03.04.2023.XML',
 '05.04.2023.XML',
 '06.04.2023.XML',
 '07.04.2023.XML',
 '07.04.2023.xml',
 '10.04.2023.XML',
 '10.04.2023.XML',
 '11.04.2023.xml',
 '12.04.2023.XML',
 '13.04.2023.XML',
 '13.04.2023.XML',
 '14.04.2023.XML',
 '14.04.2023.XML',
 '17.04.2023.XML',
 '17.04.2023.XML',
 '18.04.2023.XML',
 '19.04.2023.XML',
 '19.04.2023.XML',
 '20.04.2023.XML',
 '21.04.2023.XML',
 '24.04.2023.XML',
 '25.04.2023.XML',
 '26.04.2023.XML',
 '27.03.2023.XML',
 '27.03.2023.XML',
 '28.03.2023.XML',
 '28.03.2023.XML',
 '29.03.2023.XML',
 '29.03.2023.XML',
 '30.03.2023.XML',
 '30.03.2023.XML']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, обрезать расширение, преобразовать в дату и сортировать уже как даты, а не как строки:

```
from datetime import datetime

b = sorted(a, key=lambda item: datetime.strptime(item.rpartition(".")[0], "%d.%m.%Y"))

from pprint import pprint
pprint(b)
```

Вывод:

```
['27.03.2023.XML',
 '27.03.2023.XML',
 '28.03.2023.XML',
 '28.03.2023.XML',
 '29.03.2023.XML',
 '29.03.2023.XML',
 '30.03.2023.XML',
 '30.03.2023.XML',
 '03.04.2023.XML',
 '05.04.2023.XML',
 '06.04.2023.XML',
 '07.04.2023.xml',
 '07.04.2023.XML',
 '10.04.2023.XML',
 '10.04.2023.XML',
 '11.04.2023.xml',
 '12.04.2023.XML',
 '13.04.2023.XML',
 '13.04.2023.XML',
 '14.04.2023.XML',
 '14.04.2023.XML',
 '17.04.2023.XML',
 '17.04.2023.XML',
 '18.04.2023.XML',
 '19.04.2023.XML',
 '19.04.2023.XML',
 '20.04.2023.XML',
 '21.04.2023.XML',
 '24.04.2023.XML',
 '25.04.2023.XML',
 '26.04.2023.XML']
```